# sending JSON string from one HTML page to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I know this might sound silly and the easier alternative is to convert my pages to PHP. But is there a way to do this in HTML with Javascript or jQuery?

i want to sending JSON string from one HTML page to another.

in `first.html` there is a set of images that gets converted into a JSON string that looks like this:

```
{"images":[ {"src":"images/en1.png"},
    {"src":"images/en4.png"},
    {"src":"images/en2.png"},
    {"src":"images/fr4.png"},
    {"src":"images/b40.png"},
    {"src":"images/ca7.png"}
]}
```

i want to send this to  `second.html` and in there a button called **edit** will take all this back to `first.html`

Is there a way to do this or is it impossible?

Comment: given that you're dealing with client-only functionality, you might do better to just use jQuery to show/hide sections on a single HTML page, this will probably be less complicated and more reliable than trying to serialized/deserialize a cookie..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use querystring for that

something like

```
    <a 
href='second.htm?images={"images":[ {"src":"images/en1.png"},{"src":"images/en4.png"},{"src":"images/en2.png"},{"src":"images/fr4.png"},"src":"images/b40.png"},{"src":"images/ca7.png"}]}' >
    Go to second page
    </a>
```

and on second.htm you can get that value by using

```
window.location.href
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

cookies to store the string and read the cookie in second html

passing the entire string(JSON stringify) as a URL parameter

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of HTML5 offline storage using Andris Reinman's [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) library. Just call the `set` method from your first.html page and the `get` method from your second.html page.